# I cannot find a link for Purchase Order in zencart

Tags: php, database, zen-cart

I have installed super order , ty package tracker and Purchase order plugins in my zencart.
There are links for showing for all in the zencart configuration dropdown except i cannot see a link for the purchase order module under the configuration in admin panel of zencart.
When i see the configuration_group table in database i found that sort_order column value is the same for the super orders and purchase orders but the configuration_group_id column value for both are different. I guess if this may be causing the problem, i really cannot find the solution. Although when i give the link manually for the purcahse order settings i see its details but i need that link in the drop down under configuration
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your module hasn't registered itself to the Admin Menu system. If it's not registered to the menu, then the security tools won't allow it to show because it will appear as though you're not authorized to use it.